# Android Gallery changing the default layout

Tags: android, gallery

I am trying to implement a gallery which always starts from left rather than center of the screen.
I have already overridden `onLayout` and `onDraw` methods and it works for the first time, but if I scroll the gallery, it again center itself to center.

Do you have any idea how to implement this?
Or I am thinking of backup solution: if it's possible to make an horizontal listView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used **Android Horizontal ListView** from below link with some modificqations to suit my needs

http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question:

[Android horizontal scroll list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537310/android-horizontal-scroll-list/5537402#5537402)

Comment: the idea given on that page doesnt implements adapter and thus not memory optimized if the child items are large in number as I have many child to be added