# android: Scrolling list view Horizontal is it possible?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

I have database with 3 field that I connect to listview (my custome listview from xml file).

When the list is Filled with data, the listview can Scrolling up and down.

But what will happen if I have 15 fields on my database?  How to make the listview

Scrolling right and left?  Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Here you can find some posts about the same issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I think, this answer and it's comments will be very helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6235806/625676

Answer (score 1):

see this link:

http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

code can be found on http://www.dev-smart.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1

you will find how to scroll list view horizontally.

Comment: thank for the help !, but in this example only the row can move right or left and i need that the all listview will move right or left

Answer (score 1):

Refer to following links::

1)[Android horizontal scroll list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537310/android-horizontal-scroll-list)

2)[Horizontal ListView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

3)[(Android) How to use horizontal scrolling in a ListView](http://nan-devblog.blogspot.in/2008/12/android-how-to-use-horizontal-scrolling.html)

4)[Android Horizontal ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)