# Sliding Images horizontally in a Listview? - Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've a Listview where can be text or images in each rows.. If the row has images I need to add horizontal slide option, so that the users can view the images with the finger touch.

To achieve this, I used ViewPager in every row(where there are images). I've couple of questions..

1. Is it fine to use ViewPager in multiple rows in a listview? I read somewhere that ViewPager is not intended to be used as an item in a list.. If so, what should I use to slide images in a row?
2. The scrolling experience of ViewPager is terrible.. When I scroll horizontally in the images and accidentally scroll upwards/downwards the listview scroll is getting fired and start to scroll vertically, thereby ending the horizontal scroll. I'm banging my head for the last few days to solve this problem. Any pointers?

Comment: Check the answers on this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android][1]

Hope this Helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android

Comment: and check this too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537310/android-horizontal-scroll-list

Comment: @sulemankhan thanks.. In the links that you had mentioned they are suggesting to use HorizontalScrollView.. I tried it earlier, but the problem with HSV is that it is not possible to scroll/slide one item at a time.. Any workarounds for that?